# DataFlow outputting multiple files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Seeing something odd when i process a big file (5 million+ lines). In code, my number of shards is set to 1. Yet, when i am seeing upwards of 15 files being kicked out, and i am not sure why. A google search hasn't yielded me anything to explain why this is occurring.

As a snippet, here is the output portion:

```
    results.get(valid).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()).apply("Build Window For Valid Entries", Window.<String>into(new GlobalWindows()).triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.ZERO))).withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes())
    .apply("Write valid to GCS", TextIO.write().to(validFileLocation).withSuffix(".csv").withWindowedWrites().withNumShards(1));
```

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Is your source bounded or unbounded ? It's kind of strange to use a GlobalWindow to use WindowedWrites. Also, I don't understand why you use triggering in a GlobalWindow.

Comment: Unbounded sources

Comment: I had a different configuration (Interval if I recall correctly). However, when I deployed to beam, it gave me an error where I wasn’t allowed to use intervals, and to use global window, which I though was weird. It worked when I switched though.

Comment: What I really need to do is when the last element is received, and 30 seconds has passed, output the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. GlobalWindows are fine, but the best way to do what i was trying to do is by using Session windows. This solves the issue.

an example would be Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(10))))

this says, "after 10 seconds of the last data packet received, if i don't get anything else, proceed to output"

Answer (score 0):

If your input is unbounded, then how do you expect to write only one file?

TextIO must either wait for the end of the unbounded input, or shard it using windowing (bounding data).

I dont know the expected behavior of triggering on a GlobalWindow, maybe only the last file contains all the data? Or maybe you hit a size limit of GCS?

Furthermore, GCS does not allow modifications on files, you can only add or delete a file.